# How to check user exist in Camunda via Java SDK?

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda-modeler

I want to check user existence in Camunda java API. I asked this question from Chatgpt and said use Camunda client library. But i not found library of that or that method. Is there a way to solve this problem? I don't want to use password checker because this way id not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are looking for is the [IdentityService](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.18/org/camunda/bpm/engine/IdentityService.html). It provides a query method:

```
identityService.createUserQuery()
    .userId("id")
    .singleResult()
```